# Flask/Python - loses styling

Tags: python, flask

this is the my first time using S/O, so I apologize if I am not exactly following posting norms.

My problem is with using Python Flask, and creating an app route that takes more than one argument.

This is my code:

```
     @app.route('/edit/<title>/<chapter>/<section>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
     def edit_form(title, chapter, section):
          if request.method == 'GET':
               return render_template("edit/edit_form.html", title=title, chapter=chapter, section=section)
```

This loses my styling. However, if I pass in 1 or 0 arguments to edit_form, it maintains the same styling as the rest of my templates. What's going on, and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I managed to figure out the problem - it was a scoping issue. My base.html was written in a way such that it would only go up one level. However when I am working with directories inside directories, it will noot be able to find the folder it doesn't need. The fix was to create a different base.html (or to edit the original base.html to go up multiple levels, since if there is no higher directory it will just stop going up even if ".." is in the code.

Comment: Can you post your `edit_form.html` template?

Comment: Rather than using a bunch of `../../../..` and expecting the browser to stop when it gets to the root, you can just prefix the path with `/` and it will be relative to the root of the domain.

Comment: Wow, that is a much better solution. Thanks a bunch!